# What is the current status of neuroeducation?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, educational-psychology, neuropsychology

How can we apply the cognitive neuroscience in the classroom?
What is a good general reference discussing the current status of neuroeducation?

Comment: I've tried to make this more concrete than just "what do you think of x?" However, the question probably needs more development in terms of what you're hoping to find out.

Answer (score 2):

The general is that neuroeducation or educational neuroscience holds great promise for the future, but is in a very early stage of development. There is great interest in the topic, which is evident in scientific journal, textbooks, and science centres dedicated to the topic that have recently been created. These are good sources of reference as well.

Journals:

Educational Neuroscience: https://uk.sagepub.com/en-gb/eur/educational-neuroscience/journal202455

Trends in Neuroscience and Education: http://www.journals.elsevier.com/trends-in-neuroscience-and-education/

Book:

Educational Neuroscience: http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1119973198.html

Scientific centres:

These centres will often organise seminars, workshops, or other events and have a list of their research output and current projects on their websites.

http://www.educationalneuroscience.org.uk
http://www.cne.psychol.cam.ac.uk

As an introduction, I recommend the following Opinion Article:

Goswami, U. (2006). Neuroscience and education: from research to practice? Nature Reviews Neuroscience, 7(5), 406–413. doi:10.1038/nrn1907

Please note that this is not a comprehensive list, but just some resources that I can recommend as someone working in a related field.